# A non well formed numeric value encountered, but all numbers

Tags: php, date

I am trying to add 28 days to a date and keep getting the following error:

> Message: A non well formed numeric value encountered

My code is:

```
    $expirationDate = 1396885780;

    $entryDate = 1396885780;

    if ($expirationDate) {
        $expiration = time(strtotime($expirationDate, '+28 day'));          
    } else {
        $expiration = time(strtotime($entryDate, '+28 day'));           
    }
```

So basically I am passing a %U format date (which I think is universal) and wanting to add 28 days to it.

Can anyone see the issue here?

Answer (score 1):

Argument 2 when calling [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date
> format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the
> number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), **relative to the
> timestamp given in now**, or the current time if now is not supplied.

And then there is no need to call time() to try and convert that to a timestamp, because strtotime() returns a timestamp already

```
$expirationDate = 1396885780;

$entryDate = 1396885780;

if ($expirationDate) {
    $expiration = strtotime('+28 day', $expirationDate);
} else {
    $expiration = strtotime('+28 day', $entryDate);
}
```